# Run a function from shortcut generated by program

Tags: c#

I'm looking to create a program which 'Cleans the desktop'

Basically I want to create a shorter way of doing this without having to enter the program,

Would it be possible to create a .lnk file on the desktop that runs a certain function in the program so it doesn't start the programs form but just performs the function? (cleaning desktop).

The program should also be able to open up but through another shortcut.
I hope this makes sense...

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, All you want to do is create an appliaction without a UI (something to run in the background).

If so. Just create a windows application and never show your window.

If you have a console application, just change it to windows application in the properties of the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your program in Windows Forms, you can use command line parameter to differentiate its behavior:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args.Length > 1 && args[1].Equals("--cleanup-only"))
        {
            // Desktop cleanup code, without GUI
        }
        else
        {
            // Normal execution
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
}
```

and then create a shortcut with `--cleanup-only` parameter specified.